# Hash function: Hash key (name of data object) into XY coordinate

Tags: function, hash, coordinates

Dear everyone,
I'm trying to the find the hash function which can hash the key ( in string value) into XY coordinate.
For example: H("Doraemon") = (1.2345 , 3.2345)

If you have any information about this: algorithm , source code in C++ ... or something like that. Please share for me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Get the SHA-1 or MD5 hash, as bits, and take half of them for X, half for Y. Of each half, use as many bits (big-endian) as you can, for example use the first 64 bits of each half (out of 80) and there you have a double value.